# How to use double value in Text widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, text, integer, double

I got a response from API which is

```
{"id":1,"title":"Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops","price":109.95,"description":"Your perfect pack for everyday use and walks in the forest. Stash your laptop (up to 15 inches) in the padded sleeve, your everyday","category":"men's clothing","image":"https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg","rating":{"rate":3.9,"count":120}},
```

I'm display `price` into `Text` widget but it gives me this error

`type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'`
please let me know how to display double value in text widget

**ProductModel class:**

```
class ProductModel {
  ProductModel(
      {required this.title,
      required this.id,
      required this.urlImage,
      required this.price});

  String title;
  int id;
  String urlImage;
  String price;

  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductModel(
      id: json["id"],
      title: json["price"],
      urlImage: json["image"],
      price: json["price"]);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {"id": id, "title": title, "image": urlImage, "price": price};
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you.

Your var declaration:

```
double price = 109.95;
```

Your Widget:

**Using String Interpolation:**

```
    Text(
        'Price: $price',
      ),
```

OR **Using toString():**

```
  Text(
         price.toString() ,
      ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @Ravindra is correct but you need to fix your model.

First, change price type to double

Second, change

```
price: json['price']
```

to

```
price: (json['price'] as num)?.toDouble()
```

Comment: i did that, thank you